# How to pass "sample%04d.png" as a command line parameter?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, command-line-arguments

If I pass the command line parameters via *Properties* - *Debug* - *Command Arguments* as "sample%04d.png", it will become "sample\x4d.png".

I tried various combinations but nothing worked. How can I prevent this % expansion?

Comment: Did you try `sample\%04d.png`?

Comment: Will become sample\\\x4d.png